# How can I force my ultragrid bands to be expandable

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

grid.DisplayLayout.ViewStyle is set to Multiband.

Once upon a time, the application I am working on used to display bands with a "+" and lines connecting the bands (rows and sub rows). When selecting the "+" the bands would toggle appearing and hiding. I did many changes to the grid and somehow this + disappeared and the user can no longer change the appearance of the bands. What could I have possibly done to cause this?  Yes I am sure that the ViewStyle is set to Multiband.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter I was looking for was `ExpansionIndicator`. I could not search for it because I did not know what to call it.

```
UltraGrid TheGridIron = new UltraGrid();
TheGridIron.DisplayLayout.Override.ExpansionIndicator = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ShowExpansionIndicator.Always;
```

This link provided me the answer: [Infragistics(R) NetAdvantage(R) Windows Forms ExpansionIndicator Property](https://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow~ExpansionIndicator.html)